# FFMPEG Segment name

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to save a segment from ffmpeg but keep on getting the following error:

```
[mpegts @ 0000000003a20560] Invalid segment filename template 'Test-%date:~7,4%
%date:~3,3%-%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.ts'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Inval
d argument
```

I do understand the way i'm trying to get the date/time in there is not correct. Can someone help me correct it please.

Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://10.0.0.239:1234 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_format ts "Test-
%date:~7,4%-%date:~3,3%-%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.ts"
```

Comment: It has to be strftime formatted. What's the format that you need?

Comment: I need it in the format ddmmyy-hhmm

Answer (score 3):

Try this option `-strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg"`

Comment: i think we need to include playback timestamp related details, not the system's current date/time when making the file.